# vs.net asp.net mvc grunt referencing css / javascript (release vs debug)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, gruntjs

I was wondering how you guys handle release vs debug when using grunt and the Task Runner Explorer.

With asp.net mvc and bundleconfig you could output the release version or the debug versions of files (debug would have multiple files, release just the one)

With grunt I set up a dev and release version
DEV style.css
RELEASE style.min.css

My question is how do you guys reference the right file depending on the current build automatically.

**DEBUG**

```
<script src="/css/style.css" />
```

**RELEASE**

```
<script src="/css/style.min.css" />
```

Would I have to use something like wiredep to search and replace files? Or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a better idea on how to achieve this, by following this example

http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/05/web-optimization-development-and-production-in-asp-net-mvc6.aspx

Hope this helps others